# Bootstrap input inside column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, width

I have my HTML like this

```
<div class="col-lg-4"><input type="text"></div>
```

How can I make the input width stretched at column size?

Answer (score 1):

Put the class `form-control` to the input element.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <input class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```